# nginx, redirect to remove a part of filename

Tags: nginx, redirect, regex

I know there are plenty of questions how to replace part of URL with something else (or nothing) in nginx but I really suck in regular expressions and am absolute noob in nginx.

So could anybody explain how to convert URL like `http://123.123.123.123:9090/v0/A8B9DEBF512F929144257AEE00262C16/$File/IMG_8819.jpg` to `http://123.123.123.123:9090/v0/A8B9DEBF512F929144257AEE00262C16/IMG_8819.jpg` (without $File/, instead of A8B9DEBF512F929144257AEE00262C16 and IMG_8819.jpg there may be any combination of digits and letters)?

I tried something like this

```
    location /v0 {
        rewrite ^(v0/[^/]+)/\$File/(.*)$ $1/$2 last;
    }
```

with no avail. But obviously it's regex that's wrong, 'cause at least nginx recognizes that it should do something with /v0/ and I get 404.